# Duplicate a row multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically I want to duplicate a row a variable number of times.
I have a table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Start](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Apt] [int] NOT NULL,
[Cost] [int] NOT NULL)
```

I want to duplicate each row in this table (Apt-1) times so in the end there will be #Apt rows. Moreover for each new row the value of Cost is decremented until it reaches 0. ID will be the same as there are no primary keys. If I have a record like this:

```
1    5    3
```

I need 4 new rows inserted in the same table and they should look like this

```
1    5    2
1    5    1
1    5    0
1    5    0
```

I have tried so far a lot of ways but I cannot make it work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE  @Start TABLE ( 
[ID] [int] NOT NULL, 
[Apt] [int] NOT NULL, 
[Cost] [int] NOT NULL) 

INSERT @Start (ID, Apt, Cost)
VALUES  (1, 5, 3)



; WITH CTE_DIGS AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
    FROM master.sys.all_columns AS a
)
INSERT @Start (ID, Apt, Cost)
SELECT ID, Apt, CASE WHEN Cost - rn < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Cost - rn END
FROM @Start
INNER JOIN CTE_DIGS
    ON Apt > rn
```

Comment: Great! It works. Many thanks. Now I have to break it down and understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
;with cte as 
(select [ID], [Apt], [Cost], 1 counter from [Start]
 union all
 select [ID], 
        [Apt], 
        case sign([Cost]) when 1 then [Cost]-1 else 0 end [Cost], 
        counter+1 counter 
 from cte where counter < [Apt])
select [ID], [Apt], [Cost]
from cte
```

Comment: It picks only the last row in column and does the row generation correct. The problem is it never stops and I get following error: 'The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.' Excepting the last row the procedure is not performed for any of the other ones.